# How to pass COM pointer from one process to another?

Tags: visual-c++, marshalling, atlcom

I have an interface pointer to an COM object sitting within process 1. I would like to get access to the same object from another process. How can I achieve this purpose? I believe directly passing over the pointer wouldn't work due to different address spaces. I know it involves the marshaling/proxy/stub stuff. But I don't know details.

Can somebody provide some detailed instructions regarding the steps to follow and the functions to call? Thanks a lot. I am not the designer for the COM object itself. I am just using it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to understand the basics of COM to make this work.  Basically process 1 is an out-of-proc server for your client (the second process).  Take a dig around in the COM docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683835%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), especially [Getting a Pointer to an Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682305%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).